# Apache Kylin Hive table schema require Streaming cluster settings

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, kylin

I created Hive table over my HBase table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(key string, value string, value1 string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key, g:array, g:key")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "close-counter-accounts");
```

and connected it to Kylin. But when I try to build cube I get one strange [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXMbt.png) about Apache.Kafka

Also DataSource page require to setup [Streaming cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDwq8.png) settings that sounds very strange couse its table mapped data

Did anybody have that kind of problem like me?

Comment: I forgot to say that i'm using: 
Apache.Kylin 2.0.0
Apache.Hive 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was a problem in bad kylin configuration. Reinstall kylin helped